# How do I change the html on my site to make it general on all pages?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I run I site in Wordpress:
http://brfrodakvarn.se/
On the news page, http://brfrodakvarn.se/nyheter/ I would like to change the text where it says "Share your thoughts" to something else. If I right-click on the text and inspect it (Chromium) I can see the html but where do I find that page in the Wordpress dashboard to make the changes general for all the news? Or do I make the changes in css?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring Wordpress, not programming. You'd probably get a better response over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: OK, thank you. I didn'nt know whether to put it here or wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be specific to your theme, but in the default wordpress theme (Twenty Twelve), the comment link text is in the file called "content.php". In the Appearance Editor, find content.php, and change the text "Share Your thoughts" to something else.

Answer (score 0):

First thing it has to be asked in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

But here is your answer, you got to design your own theme. Wordpress has provided documentation where you can develop a list of themes and can use it as per your needs.

go through this link, it will help you out.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Thank you for the link and for the advice. To develop my own theme would be something I might do in the future and something I'm interested in learning - but for the time being I'm happy with the theme someone else has created.